# Create a grid inside shapefile for kriging based on meuse.grid

Tags: r, geospatial, kriging

I was trying to follow [this kriging exercise](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/80464_9156596afb2e4dcda53e3650a68df82a.html) and ended up going on a 6 hour adventure in an attempt to create a grid file like meuse.grid in the link. I'm very new to R and geostats in general so I'd really appreciate any help. I managed to create a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame using a shapefile to get: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/468Jk.png)

```
cishape <- st_read("data/files/cishape.shp")
map <- as_Spatial(cishape)
plot(map)
```

I then managed to get this which seems to be closer to correct although the shape is now [more off:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APzJO.png)

```
grd <- makegrid(poly, n=10000); colnames(grd) <-c("x", "y"); 
grd_pts <- SpatialPoints(coords=grd, proj4string = CRS(proj4string(poly))); 
grd_pts_in <- grd_pts[poly,];
gdf <- as.data.frame(coordinates(grd_pts_in));
ggplot(gdf) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y))
```

I can't seem to make this work following the kriging exercise though. When I make it to the bit where: 
`grd <- as(grd, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame`

`plot(grd)`, I get the error: `Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds`. I read that it is because my spdf is actually has no data and should use `SpatialPixels` instead, but then I get the error `Error in matrix(FALSE, ncells[2], ncells[1]) : invalid 'nrow' value (too large or NA)`. So then I tried `SpatialPoints` instead and got this [chunk.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGuMl.png)

Please help, I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I feel like I'm losing my sanity.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow!!! Please provide a sample of your data with ````dput()```` so that users can test their solutions with your data.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?